# Hovering on menu shows the list of dropdown menu in every menus

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in web developing, when I hover my mouse to the list of my menus the dropdown menu keeps on showing in every menu. What seems to be the problem?

I tried removing the  so I can use "ul li ul li" directly in css but it doesn't work and also when I try ".site-header nav ul li:hover .sub-menu-about" there is no output but ".site-header nav ul:hover .sub-menu-about" I've got the same problem even when I use ".site-header ul:hover .sub-menu-about" still the same problem.

Here is my CSS code

```
.sub-menu-about{
display: none;
}

.site-header ul:hover .sub-menu-about {
display: block;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: -15px;
position: absolute;
}

.main-navigation ul:hover .sub-menu-about ul{
display: block;
margin: 10px;
}
```

and this is my html code

```
  <div class="site-header__menu group">
    <nav class="main-navigation">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <div class="sub-menu-about">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">History</li>
              <li><a href="#">Vision</li>  
              <li><a href="#">Mission</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
```

Once I hover on the about menu, a dropdown list of History, Mission, Vision will be shown. and when I hover on different menus there will be no dropdown menu will be shown

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to attach a working snippet or fiddle.Your html code right now is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error No. 1: The submenu should be located inside the `<li>` tag. Corrected

Error No. 2:
First, you hide the class `.sub-menu-about` through `displays: none`, and then you try to show not this class itself, but a list inside it. Corrected

**Result**

```css
.sub-menu-about {
  display: none;
}

.site-header ul:hover .sub-menu-about {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.main-navigation li:hover .sub-menu-about {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-header__menu group">
  <nav class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <div class="sub-menu-about">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">History</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vision</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mission</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
          </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: When I added an "ul li:hover .sub-menu-about" when I hover there are no outputs at all.

Comment: @bonbon, You have not posted a complete snippet of code. It does not work, since there are no certain elements. Please complete it so that you can show you the result

Comment: @bonbon, I updated the answer. Pointed out errors and provided the correct version of the code.

Comment: thank you and It works but there's another problem when I hover it on "About" its like the sub menus are blinking rapidly. my css has already 2443 lines. I really don't know what to do,

Comment: Can you record screencast? It’s hard to understand your problem as described

Comment: sorry about that, but it seems its working, and another problem encountered. If i hover on the "About" the sub menus are showing but it doesn't hold up. I can't click on the sub menus.

Comment: https://imgur.com/zFSJilV here's what happen, when I'm "about" tab the sub menus are shown but when I'm about to choose from the sub menus. the sub menus are gone. I have to hover on the about tab again. But when I'm about to choose from the sub menus the sub menus disappear again.

Comment: The problem is in positioning the submenu relative to parent `<li>` element. I cannot fix it without access to all the code.

Comment: @bonbon, If my answer and comments helped solve the main problem described in the question, please mark it with a solution.

Comment: sorry about that, can  you please elaborate about the relative to parent <Li> element. I don't know how to send you the code. thank you for giving extra time for me.

Comment: You can share the archive with the files of your project. For example, through this service: https://fex.net/ or any other

Comment: You sent only the contents of the CSS file. And in a file with the txt extension. I meant the html and CSS file archive

Comment: II'm sorry about that, I'm new to this. is this the right? https://fex.net/s/6vy51yp

Comment: Done. You can check it: http://hisbvdis-pic.zzz.com.ua/drafts/files.zip

Comment: Thank you, what seems to be the problem? can you guide me so when I encounter same problem I know how to fix it.